# prepend after element

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to prepend after a certain element? For example, I am prepending a hyperlink to a div however there is already an element in there represented as `<a id="test">test1</a>` Is it possible to prepend the test2 hyperlink after the test1 hyperlink?

```
  $('div[id='+id+']').prepend('<a id="test">test2</a>');
```

Comment: `<nitpick>` How do you *pre* pend something after an element? Wouldn't that be *post* pend? `</nitpick>`

Comment: @Pekka The word, I think, is *ap*-pend ;-)

Comment: @lonesomeday true - it's jQuery's syntax as well, now that I think of it. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to place it after the other element, like this:

```
$('#test').after('<a id="test2">test2</a>');
```